# Variable length input in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

The shape of input is `[batch_size, maxstep, 50, 50]`. And I want to use a certain cnn at each step to make it become `[batch_size, maxstep, 5 * 5 * 32]`. At first glance, I think I should use `while_loop`.

But it is difficult to build this graph, the "maxstep" and "batch_size" are both variable, so how to iterate this tensor?

This is my wrong code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, None, None, 50, 50])
source = list()
target = list()

W_conv, B_conv = weight_and_bias('conv', [5, 5, 1, 32])

for e in x[0]:
    e_tmp = tf.reshape(e, [-1, 50, 50 ,1])
    h_conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(e_tmp, W_conv) + B_conv)
    h_pool = max_pool_2x2(h_conv)
    h_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 5 * 5 * 32])
    source.append(e_tmp)

for e in x[1]:
    e_tmp = tf.reshape(e, [-1, 50, 50 ,1])
    h_conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(e_tmp, W_conv) + B_conv)
    h_pool = max_pool_2x2(h_conv)
    h_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 5 * 5 * 32])
    target.append(e_tmp)

source = np.array(source)
target = np.array(target)
```

Comment: Most of these ops accept a batch dimension and efficiently perform their operations on that batch (much faster than iterating). Is there some reason you can't just combine the first two dimensions as a single batch dimension (with reshape), then call the ops normally?

Comment: @AllenLavoie You mean combine the "batch_size" and "maxstep"? Actually, it is a sequential problem, and after cnn ops, I still need to feed the batch with shape `[batch_size, maxstep, 5*5*32]` into a dynamic_rnn. So if combine the first two dimensions, the sequential information will lose.

Comment: Can't you just reshape it back into [batch_size, maxstep, ...] after the convolutions are done, then do whatever sequential processing you need on that?

Comment: @AllenLavoie Umm...I think I get your point. But first I'm not sure about that will the merge and split ops maintain the original sequence. And second the `maxstep` and `batch_size` are both variable, maybe I can use padding to make the `maxstep` to be a constant. This maybe a solution if the sequence is not changed.

Comment: tf.reshape doesn't actually change the in-memory representation: it's just meta-data about the actual values, which are stored in a flat array in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). You can reference a variable shape as an integer Tensor using [tf.shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#shape).

Comment: @AllenLavoie Oh, thanks a lot. I will have a try. If I can success, I will answer this question by myself.

Answer (score 0):

With [AllenLavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6824418/allen-lavoie)'s help, I finally solved this problem.

First I pad the input's shape `[batch_size, variable_step_len, 50, 50]` into `[batch_size, max_step_len, 50, 50]`, and then reshape it into `[batch_size*max_step_len, 50, 50]`.

Second I op cnn on it and reshape it back.

Comment: Isn't there an issue with the solution.
Suppose my features are (x,50,50) where x ranges from 100 to 1500. Won't that leave a lot of zeros in the network. My suggestion would be to divide the larger ones into small samples and pass it through the CNN.